# Exeption in upload file

Tags: php, upload, cmis

I have a problem uploading a file in a php class:
as soon as I upload the file, I create a new document in Alfresco through the php-cmis-client library. However, before instantiating the library client I get a "Serialization of Closure not alloweed in .." type,  I report the code that throws the exception:

```
 $this->alfrescoHttpInvoker = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
        ['auth' =>
            [
                CMIS_BROWSER_USER,
                CMIS_BROWSER_PASSWORD
            ]
        ]);
```

```
class Client implements ClientInterface{
    private $config;
```

`public function __construct(array $config = [])    {
    if (!isset($config['handler'])) {
        $config['handler'] = HandlerStack::create();
    } elseif (!is_callable($config['handler'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('handler must be a callable');
    }

    // Convert the base_uri to a UriInterface
    if (isset($config['base_uri'])) {
        $config['base_uri'] = Psr7\uri_for($config['base_uri']);
    }

    $this->configureDefaults($config);
 }...}`

How to change the client class so that the exception is not launched?